# Problema abriendo imagen con openCV c++

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

Estoy intentando abrir una imagen con opencv, soy completamente nuevo y he seguido varios tutoriales pero el programa siempre me indica que no se pudo encontrar el archivo, ya he probado de varias maneras pero aun no logro abrir la imagen.

```
int main()
{
    String ubicacion = "C:/imagesamples/patito.jpg";
    Mat image;
    image = imread(ubicacion);  

    if (!image.data)                        
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        waitKey(1000);
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display window", image);               

    waitKey(1000);                                       
    return 0;
}
```